# MySQL: how to set a different config file on Windows?

Tags: mysql

I did the following,

```
mysqld.exe --defaults-file="D:\my-large.ini"
```

I changed the `max_allowed_packets` inside of that `.ini` but I'm still receiving the error.  How do I know that MySQL loaded that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `max_allowed_packets` from the mysql prompt like so:

```
show variables like '%max_allowed%';
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was
 1. start Mysql workbench 5.6
 2. In the navigator go to Instance options file.
 3. Click the networking
 4. Enter 16M in the max_allowed_packet edit box, click apply and restart mysql
 5. Show variables like 'max_allowed_packet' will now give 16777216